# How to delete unused icon from launchpad?

Tags: launchpad

This is my first Mac and I've had it for less then a day.

I downloaded an iPod to Mac a transfer program and after using it I wanted to get rid of it. For some reason the icon stays in the launchpad but the actual program does not exist on my Mac anymore. It also doesn't show up when I look for it in my files through the Finder.

I'd like to get rid of it as it is cluttering up my launchpad, but how?

Comment: Is this either reproducible, or solved by the two answers? One addresses corruption in the database (unlikely but harder to fix and diagnose) and the other covers how deleting apps normally should work.

Answer (score 1):

Click and hold on an icon in Launchpad.  After a while, they start quivering.  The ones purchased from the App Store have a little x on them.  Click it.

More info here http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5548

If not from the App Store, and you can't find it?  Well, run it, then right-click on the icon in the Dock and choose "Show in Finder" to see where it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a utility such as [Launchpad Control](http://chaosspace.de/launchpad-control/) or [LaunchpadEditor](http://horizon-nigh.org/launchpad-editor.html) - or delete the .db file at `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/(long, random string of numbers and letters).db` then reboot.